# Intellij: How to copy/paste a file in order to duplicate it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can not seem to find a way to do this? I have a file named X in some folder, I want to create Y with the same contents in the same directory. The way I do in eclipse is to select the file and ^C, ^P, eclipse prompts for the new name.

**UPDATE**

Apparently this problem only occurs if compilation unit contains more than one type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## ⌥ + drag

- **Mac**
  Press <kbd>Option</kbd> key and drag the original file.
- **PC**
  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and drag the original file.

You will be prompted for a new name.

[image]

Works for classes too:

[image]

Comment: The same dialog pops up when pressing F5.

Comment: This is the dialog I get with the files multiple types defined. try doing this on A.java : public class A {} class B{}

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Scala classes. It shows a dialog like the above, but only lets you specify the directory and not the name.

Comment: I just tried it with Scala class, and it displays "Copy Class" dialog, not "Copy" dialog. You specify which package you are moving the class to and the destination directory.

Answer (score 51):

<kbd>F5</kbd> will **duplicate selected file** prompting you to enter a name for the new file.

Comment: Function key has nothing to do in this answer. It might work for you if you are on a laptop which has the function key autoenabled, in which case you need to press action key to get F5 functionality. Most users will not need that.
The correct answer is F5 opens a copy dialog with the current path being default copy-to path and a filename prompt. Changing the filename and pressing ok/enter will copy the file with a new name to the current location.

Comment: By function key = WinKey for Windows OS, WinKey + f5 makes a duplicate with renaming dialog.

Answer (score 6):

As for a keyboard only solution to duplicate a file in IntelliJ:

On Linux:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to activate the navigation bar, then either press <kbd>F5</kbd>, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the file and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it, a dialog will appear to name your new file.

On Mac:

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to activate the navigation bar, then either press <kbd>F5</kbd>, or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the file and then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it, a dialog will appear to name your new file.

Comment: Does not work (2016.2 on mac).  The Alt-home does activate the nav bar but Ctl-C /Ctl-V combo does nothing.

Comment: On a mac you can use Cmd + Up to activate the nav bar (I am using the keymap Mac OS X 10.5+)

Answer (score 0):

I found that ctrl+c/ctrl+v will not copy files on IDEA in Linux (using x2go to connect on a Windows box).  I was able to get it working if I close xclipboard but then copying between Windows and Linux dialogs stops working.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + C on target file/folder

Ctrl + V on destination folder

Enter new name and press Enter...