# How to duplicate a Scala class in the same directory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm surprised that IntelliJ 13.1.6 can't do this.

I've tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173756/intellij-how-to-copy-paste-a-file-in-order-to-duplicate-it) but it shows the pictured dialog without the ability to specify a file name. So choosing the same directory causes an error saying we can't create the file because it already exists (obviously -- I want to be able to rename it!).

It only applies to files with both an class and object (or multiple of either).

[image]

Is there anything I can do to duplicate a file or must I switch to explorer and do it there?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog that is shown? When I select a class in a Scala project and hit F5 I see copy class dialog where I can select new class name and destination page.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt, I just realized it only applies to files with both the class and the object. Files with only an object or only a class don't have this problem.

Comment: I think IntelliJ thinks that the file is multiple files, for some reason. You can't edit the file unless you expand it and choose an object or class. Very annoying behavior.